# Laravel date group by year and by months

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

i've a problem with a laravel 8 query.
I've a table called `partita_pagamenti`, and my model is `PartitaPagamenti.php`.
From my table i need to take this fields `'pagatoImposta','speseTabellari','spesePieLista','pagatoMora', 'dataPagamento'` and group the results.
I have difficulty grouping items by year and then grouping them by month.
The data represents payments, so I would need to get a structure like this:

```
    2021 -> Jan -> payment list for January 2021
         -> Feb -> payment list for February 2021
            etc
    2020 -> Jan -> .....
              ..........
```

I tried this query

```
$this->report = PartitaPagamento::on($this->connection)->select('pagatoImposta','speseTabellari','spesePieLista','pagatoMora', 'dataPagamento')->get()->groupBy(function($val) {
            return Carbon::parse($val->dataPagamento)->format('Y');
        });

        $this->report = $this->report->groupBy(function($val) {
            return Carbon::parse($val->dataPagamento)->format('M');
        })->toArray();
```

but it doesn't work as I want, do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first grouping is correct. On the second one, you need to group it for each year.

```php
$this->report = PartitaPagamento::on($this->connection)
    ->select('pagatoImposta','speseTabellari','spesePieLista','pagatoMora', 'dataPagamento')
    ->get()
    ->groupBy(function ($val) {
        return Carbon::parse($val->dataPagamento)->format('Y');
    });

$this->report = $this->report
    ->map(function ($values) {
        return $values->groupBy(function ($val) {
            return Carbon::parse($val->dataPagamento)->format('M');
        });
    })
    ->toArray();
```

How to loop thru the results:

```
@foreach ($report as $year => $months)
   @foreach ($months as $month => $payments)
       @foreach ($payments as $payment)
           //
       @endforeach
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: No problem. Mark my answer as accepted. :)

Comment: Sorry, i've a question...in wich way can i access the value? I need a double cycle `@foreach` to access year and the second to access specific values?

Comment: You might need 3. First for the year, second for the months, third for the payments.

Comment: It'is a way this idea? i've see it on laravel docs
`
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

$array = ['products' => ['desk' => ['price' => 100]]];

$flattened = Arr::dot($array);

// ['products.desk.price' => 100]
`

Comment: can you explain me? this is the way?
@foreac($record['Y']) //fist cycle
@foreach($record['M']) //second cycle
@foreach($record as $r) //third cycle

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to print the values on a table and everything works fine except for the values in the red box in the image.
Those values should not be printed there, but of those values only the value 5 should be in row 2019 and column October.
This is the code with which I create the body of the table.

My Code:

```
@if(!empty($report))
                  @foreach ($report as $year => $months)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $year }}</td>
                          @foreach ($months as $month => $payments)

                                      @if($month === 'Jan' && isset($payments))
                                        <?php $pagamenti = null; ?>
                                        @foreach ($payments as $payment)
                                            <?php $pagamenti=$pagamenti+$payment['pagatoImposta']; ?>
                                        @endforeach
                                        <td>  {{$pagamenti }}</td>
                                      @else
                                        <td>0</td>
                                      @endif

                                      @if($month === 'Feb' && isset($payments))
                                        <?php $pagamenti = null; ?>
                                        @foreach ($payments as $payment)
                                            <?php $pagamenti=$pagamenti+$payment['pagatoImposta']; ?>
                                        @endforeach
                                        <td>  {{$pagamenti }}</td>
                                      @else
                                        <td>0</td>
                                      @endif

                                      @if($month === 'Mar' && isset($payments))
                                        <?php $pagamenti = null; ?>
                                        @foreach ($payments as $payment)
                                            <?php $pagamenti=$pagamenti+$payment['pagatoImposta']; ?>
                                        @endforeach
                                        <td>  {{$pagamenti }}</td>
                                      @else
                                        <td>0</td>
                                      @endif

                                      @if($month === 'Apr' && isset($payments))
                                        <?php $pagamenti = null; ?>
                                        @foreach ($payments as $payment)
                                            <?php $pagamenti=$pagamenti+$payment['pagatoImposta']; ?>
                                        @endforeach
                                        <td>  {{$pagamenti }}</td>
                                      @else
                                        <td>0</td>
                                      @endif

                                      @if($month === 'May' && isset($payments))
                                        <?php $pagamenti = null; ?>
                                        @foreach ($payments as $payment)
                                            <?php $pagamenti=$pagamenti+$payment['pagatoImposta']; ?>
                                        @endforeach
                                        <td>  {{$pagamenti }}</td>
                                      @else
                                        <td>0</td>
                                      @endif

                                      @if($month === 'Jun' && isset($payments))
                                        <?php $pagamenti = null; ?>
                                        @foreach ($payments as $payment)
                                            <?php $pagamenti=$pagamenti+$payment['pagatoImposta']; ?>
                                        @endforeach
                                        <td>  {{$pagamenti }}</td>
                                      @else
                                        <td>0</td>
                                      @endif

                                      @if($month === 'Jul' && isset($payments))
                                        <?php $pagamenti = null; ?>
                                        @foreach ($payments as $payment)
                                            <?php $pagamenti=$pagamenti+$payment['pagatoImposta']; ?>
                                        @endforeach
                                        <td>  {{$pagamenti }}</td>
                                      @else
                                        <td>0</td>
                                      @endif

                                      @if($month === 'Aug' && isset($payments))
                                        <?php $pagamenti = null; ?>
                                        @foreach ($payments as $payment)
                                            <?php $pagamenti=$pagamenti+$payment['pagatoImposta']; ?>
                                        @endforeach
                                        <td>  {{$pagamenti }}</td>
                                      @else
                                        <td>0</td>
                                      @endif

                                      @if($month === 'Sep' && isset($payments))
                                        <?php $pagamenti = null; ?>
                                        @foreach ($payments as $payment)
                                            <?php $pagamenti=$pagamenti+$payment['pagatoImposta']; ?>
                                        @endforeach
                                        <td>  {{$pagamenti }}</td>
                                      @else
                                        <td>0</td>
                                      @endif

                                      @if($month === 'Oct' && isset($payments))
                                        <?php $pagamenti = null; ?>
                                        @foreach ($payments as $payment)
                                            <?php $pagamenti=$pagamenti+$payment['pagatoImposta']; ?>
                                        @endforeach
                                        <td>  {{$pagamenti }}</td>
                                      @else
                                        <td>0</td>
                                      @endif

                                      @if($month === 'Nov' && isset($payments))
                                        <?php $pagamenti = null; ?>
                                        @foreach ($payments as $payment)
                                            <?php $pagamenti=$pagamenti+$payment['pagatoImposta']; ?>
                                        @endforeach
                                        <td>  {{$pagamenti}}</td>
                                      @else
                                        <td>0</td>
                                      @endif

                                      @if($month === 'Dec' && isset($payments))
                                        <?php $pagamenti = null; ?>
                                        @foreach ($payments as $payment)
                                            <?php $pagamenti=$pagamenti+$payment['pagatoImposta']; ?>
                                        @endforeach
                                        <td>  {{$pagamenti }}</td>
                                      @else
                                        <td>0</td>
                                      @endif
                                      <td>totale</td>
                          @endforeach        
                    </tr>
                  @endforeach
                @endif
```

Here the shot:
[TableScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aDzh.jpg)